# CSS Flexbox - Organizing flex items based on screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a container of flex items that I am trying to organize in different layouts with different number of flex items depending on screen size. For example, on desktop, I'd like to have 4 containers, each with 2 items laid out in a 2x4 grid and each cell is 1x2. What I can't seem to wrap my head around is the getting the layout on tablet using purely with flexbox. Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.data {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: middle;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }

  
  #cell1 { 
    width: 66%; 
    float: left;
  }
  
  #cell2 {
    flex-direction: column;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  #cell3 { 
    width: 66%; 
    float: left;
  }
  
  #cell4 { display: none;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  
  #cell2 {
    flex-direction: row;
    position: static;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  #cell4 { display: none; }
  
  .container { 
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .cell { 
    flex: 100%; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell" id="cell1">
    <span class="data">Image1</span>
    <span class="data">Info1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell" id="cell2">
    <span class="data">Image2</span>
    <span class="data">Info2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell" id="cell3">
    <span class="data">Image3</span>
    <span class="data">Info3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell" id="cell4">
    <span class="data">Image4</span>
    <span class="data">Info4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/phannypak60/pen/XzRaZV).

Can test responsiveness by resizing window. I was able to correctly get the layouts that I want for desktop and mobile by removing the 4th container and changing flex-direction property. Struggling to do the same for tablet to allow spanning across multiple rows/columns in flex like you can in grid layouts.

Desktop - container: 2x4 | cell: 1x2

```
|---------------------------------|
| --------------- --------------- |
| | Cell | Cell | | Cell | Cell | |
| --------------- --------------- |
| --------------- --------------- |
| | Cell | Cell | | Cell | Cell | |
| --------------- --------------- | 
|---------------------------------|
```

Tablet - container: 2x3 | cell: 1x2/2x1

```
|--------------------------|
| --------------- -------- |
| | Cell | Cell | | Cell | |
| --------------- |______| |
| --------------- |      | |
| | Cell | Cell | | Cell | |
| --------------- -------- |
|--------------------------|
```

Mobile - container: 3x2 | cell: 1x2

```
|-----------------|
| --------------- |
| | Cell | Cell | |
| --------------- |
| --------------- |
| | Cell | Cell | |
| --------------- |
| --------------- |
| | Cell | Cell | | 
| --------------- |
|-----------------|
```

Comment: Also, for desktop you have 8 items, for the other 6, so what happened with the missing 2?

Comment: @LGSon that's intentional. I'd like to display less items as the screen size decreases. More for UX/UI purposes.

Comment: Well, even intentional stuff needs to be posted along with a code sample, or else we will just guessing and you might start to say _I didn't mean like that_ or _the cells are wrapped in..._ or  _..._, so to avoid all that, update your question.

Comment: @LGSon I created a codepen with code per your suggestion and made some progress getting the desired layout I want when on mobile and desktop screens. Issue is on tablet and having a container span multiple columns as you'll see when you resize the browser window.

Comment: The answer lies within your own issue description, _having a container span multiple columns_. For it to work in tablet mode, you need to either make the `container` a flex column container, or use absolute or float to position the 2nd cell. They all have limitations when it comes to responsiveness, where i.e. the flex column container solution will need a fixed height. So which one do you want to use?

Comment: @LGSon I went down the route of using float and absolute to position the 2nd cell. I wanted to avoid having to supply in case content inside each cell is not consistent. One question I have is that with my 2nd cell in the desired position, due to the 10px padding on the container, the 2nd cell will add that extra padding to its height resulting in it overflowing outside the container. Is there a way to correct to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since comments can be removed, and to keep their value, I decided to post an answer, with this code snippet as base.

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.data {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: middle;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }

  
  #cell1 { 
    width: 66%; 
    float: left;
  }
  
  #cell2 {
    flex-direction: column;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  #cell3 { 
    width: 66%; 
    float: left;
  }
  
  #cell4 { display: none;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  
  #cell2 {
    flex-direction: row;
    position: static;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  #cell4 { display: none; }
  
  .container { 
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .cell { 
    flex: 100%; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell" id="cell1">
    <span class="data">Image1</span>
    <span class="data">Info1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell" id="cell2">
    <span class="data">Image2</span>
    <span class="data">Info2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell" id="cell3">
    <span class="data">Image3</span>
    <span class="data">Info3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell" id="cell4">
    <span class="data">Image4</span>
    <span class="data">Info4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

For it to work in tablet mode, you need to either make the `container` a flex column container, or use absolute or float to position the 2nd cell.

They all have limitations when it comes to responsiveness, where i.e. the flex column container solution will need a fixed height.

The one I find most usable is to stay with the default flex row set up, and combine it with absolute position on the 2nd cell.

This way the 1st and 3rd cell will continue being flex items, and benefit from its responsiveness.

*In case of the 2nd cell's content making it higher than the 1st/3rd, one can then either allow it to scroll, or add a small script adjusting its parent's height.*

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXWJaa)

Stack snippet

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.data {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: middle;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  
  #cell2 {
    flex-direction: row;
    position: static;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  #cell4 { display: none; }
  
  .container { 
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .cell { 
    flex: 100%; 
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #cell1 { 
    flex: 0 0 66%; 
  }
  
  #cell2 {
    flex-direction: column;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
  
  #cell3 { 
    flex:  0 0 66%; 
  }
  
  #cell4 { display: none;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell" id="cell1">
    <span class="data">Image1</span>
    <span class="data">Info1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell" id="cell2">
    <span class="data">Image2</span>
    <span class="data">Info2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell" id="cell3">
    <span class="data">Image3</span>
    <span class="data">Info3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell" id="cell4">
    <span class="data">Image4</span>
    <span class="data">Info4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```