# How to wrap four columns into two rows of two columns with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

We are using flexbox and attempting to the following below. The goal is to have one column per item on mobile breakpoints, two columns on tablet breakpoints, and four columns on desktop breakpoints.

The example uses just four items, but let's say i had 5 or 6 items, then i just wanted the items to be responsive. If the row only has enough space to display 2 items per row, then i would expect each item to continue to move below the row above it.

How can this be achieved?

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}

.flex-col {
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-col">Assertively negotiate interoperable portals without cross functional process improvements. Dramatically incentivize tactical best practices with.</div>
    <div class="flex-col">Seamlessly grow competitive.</div>
    <div class="flex-col">Distinctively optimize user-centric mindshare vis-a-vis plug-and-play infomediaries. Seamlessly optimize impactful solutions and enabled infrastructures.</div>
    <div class="flex-col">Dynamically extend flexible catalysts for change via pandemic supply chains. Efficiently.</div>
    </div>
```

Current results

[image: current]

Expected results on tablet

[image: expected]

Comment: Can you show how you are handling the breakpoints?

Comment: @KoshVery background has been swapped out with black

Comment: @MatthewStevenson i have added the code to include the media query.

Comment: @drupi17 check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236454/css-flexbox-organizing-flex-items-based-on-screen-size

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply add `flex-wrap:wrap` to allow element to go to the next line if there is no enough space and consider media query if you want to control when the break will happen:

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-col {
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .flex-col {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 12px);
  }
}

@media (max-width:460px) {
  .flex-col {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">Assertively negotiate interoperable portals without cross functional process improvements. Dramatically incentivize tactical best practices with.</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Seamlessly grow competitive.</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Distinctively optimize user-centric mindshare vis-a-vis plug-and-play infomediaries. Seamlessly optimize impactful solutions and enabled infrastructures.</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Dynamically extend flexible catalysts for change via pandemic supply chains. Efficiently.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: adding the flex-wrap:wrap makes them all go to the next line

Comment: @drupi17 on small devices yes, but not all the time

Comment: that is my problem. On small devices it works as expected by having all items go to the next line, but on tablet where i expect two rows with two items in each they are not working.

Comment: for some reason when i put that in jsfiddle, it doesn't work for me. https://jsfiddle.net/7jn8hwbc/51/

Comment: @drupi17 pay attention to margin the flex-basis is not 50% (it's updated on my answer) you need to remove the margin

Comment: @drupi17 -- while the code snippet displays correctly here, on jsfiddle it appears you have to account for the margin and the padding for it to display correctly.

Comment: @MatthewStevenson it appears the code works and as you mentioned the margin needed to be applied.

Comment: @TemaniAfif i had not added flex: 1 on the flex-col class, but now that i added it, your solution is working

Answer (score -7):

Try adding a 
 or put the first two div elements into another div with display: block. Then put the next two div elements in another div with display: block.

```
<div class="flex-row">
<div style="display: block;">
<div class="flex-col">
Assertively negotiate interoperable portals without cross functional process improvements. Dramatically incentivize tactical best practices with.
</div>
<div class="flex-col">
Seamlessly grow competitive.
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: block;">
<div class="flex-col">
Distinctively optimize user-centric mindshare vis-a-vis plug-and-play infomediaries. Seamlessly optimize impactful solutions and enabled infrastructures.
</div>
<div class="flex-col">
Dynamically extend flexible catalysts for change via pandemic supply chains. Efficiently.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It should work...

Comment: that may work but i don't believe that is true flexbox. There are scenarios where there might be 5 or 6 items in the flex-row. I cannot go into each one to have <div style: "display: block;">

Comment: If you are using PHP loops in any kind, it won't be that much hard.

Comment: Are you making a static web page? It won't be that much great.

Comment: we use Drupal so not a static page.